# How to update attributes in many to many relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new in rails. So i am not comprehending much of it. I have a database with three table. students table, courses table and registrations table.
My Railde models are as follows :

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :courses, :through => :registrations

  validates :name, :presence => true

end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :registrations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :students, :through => :registrations

  validates :name , :presence => true
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course_id, :student_id


  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student

  validates :course_id, :student_id, :presence => true
  validates :course_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :student_id}
  validates :student_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :course_id}
end
```

......................

```
Controller action for updating student :

  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
      redirect_to students_path, :notice => "Registration completed"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

................
View :

```
<%=form_for @student do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= render('course_list') %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

...............
_course_list partial :

```
Select Courses :<br/>

        <p>

          <% Course.all.each do |course| %>

              <%=check_box_tag "student[course_ids][]", course.id, `enter code here`@student.course_ids.include?(course.id) %>
              <%= course.name %>  <br/>

          <% end %>
    </p>
```

.............................
when i submit the update button, i got an error

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: course_ids

.......

parameters :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"j/lDE5bv1gWkfadQ6Cag6hGjg5nD2Ikad9vHOJTE7Pc=",
 "student"=>{"name"=>"Galib",
 "course_ids"=>["2",
 "3"]},
 "commit"=>"Update Student",
 "id"=>"6"}
```

.........................

What i want to do is, if update button is clicked, both students table and registrations table need to be updated.  Please help.

Answer (score 4):

In models define the associations

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :registrations
  has_many :courses, :through => :registrations

  validates :name, :presence => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses
  attr_accessible :course_ids

end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :registrations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :students, :through => :registrations

  validates :name , :presence => true
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :course_id, :student_id


  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student

  validates :course_id, :student_id, :presence => true
  validates :course_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :student_id}
  validates :student_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :course_id}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course
end
```

In Controller

```
def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    if @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
       @student.courses.build
      redirect_to students_path, :notice => "Registration completed"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

It may help you

Answer (score 0):

In case of MongoDB, For implementing **many to many** in rails model you have to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead of simple `has_many`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you have a permission error - `course_ids` can't be posted to from a form.  More specifically, you have `attr_accessible :name` in the Student model which means that is the only attribute that can be saved when you save a Student record using a form ([attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class) dictates what can be mass assigned).

Try changing your Student model to:

```
attr_accessible :name, :registrations_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :registrations
```

You are trying to created a nested model form, so [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is used for this.

If you want to have the Registrations table updated, as well, you're going to have to tell the partial so that it knows that the partial is updating a different model than Student.

```
<%= f.fields_for :registrations do |registration| %>
  <%= render('course_list') %>
<% end %>
```